# Regex in java to extract date and time

Tags: java, regex

Below are my sample date time format in each string

```
March 9 12:31 AM and March 10 7:30 AM
March 11 7:30 AM and March 12 10:30 AM
March 31 9:00 PM and April 1 12:39 AM
March 31 10:11 PM and April 1 5:23 AM
7:45 PM and 10:30 PM
```

My string contains following type of dates. Need to extract two date time from each string.

For ex : from string 1 need to extract date times like:

```
March 9 12:31 AM
March 10 7:30 AM
```

It should apply for all month name.
I do not want to validate 30 or 31 days in each month.

This is my current regex. It some time treat hour as date

```
(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)|(\\s)[\\d]{1,2}(?!:)|(\\s)(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)(?i)(am|pm)+
```

Can any one help me to fix this issue

Comment: Why not `"March 9 12:31 AM and March 10 7:30 AM".split(" and ")` ?

Comment: It not support for 7:45 pm and 10:30 pm and this dates be part of string

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what you want to match from each sample input, and also what your regex is *incorrectly* matching

Comment: Between May 3 4:41 PM PDT and May 4 12:19 AM PDT For this entry it matches first date correctly as (May , 3, 4:41 PM ) and next date as (May, 4 , 1) but expected is (May, 4, 12:19 AM). i believe it would clarify your question

Comment: At the outer level, your regex is a 3-way choice: `(?:monthname)` *or* `(\\s)[\\d]{1,2}(?!:)` *or* `(\\s)(1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9](\\s)(?i)(am|pm)+`. Why? Shouldn't it match `(monthname dayofmonth)? time`?

Comment: @andreas not expert in regex.  so not understand about 3 way choice. can you help me to get this date?

Comment: @MohanShanmugam Your regex has `|` where I wrote *or*, because that is what the `|` means in a regex, which you should know since you use it extensively. If you don't know what `|` means, then *learn regex*. Since you have `a|b|c`, that is a 3-way choice, i.e. regex engine must choose one of the three (`a` *or* `b` *or* `c`).

Comment: @andreas | for alternation here am looking for date and time with/without month name. so i used |. But from your comments need to look for a or b and c.

Comment: Yes, `|` means alternation, aka *or*, where regex engine must pick *one* of the alternatives. I pointed out that you regex is failing because of your use of `|`. Now that you know *why* it fails, try fixing it. --- But, since it appears that you don't know/understand how `|` works in a regex, you should probably **learn regex** before you try to fix it. --- *Note:* StackOverflow is not a write-the-code-for-me site. There are other (paid) sites for that.

Comment: @andreas thanks for your guidance finally read the pattern and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
(?:(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s[\d]{1,2}\s)?(?:1[012]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\s(?:am|pm)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jwBd88/2)

Explanation

`(?:(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\s[\d]{1,2}\s)?` matches 0 or 1 month and date combination

Comment: Why is month-day a `*` *repeating* group? Shouldn't that be a `?` *optional* group?

Comment: @Andreas, you are right. I have updated the answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Thank You @Andreas for your explaination,you have right so I need to changed my regex to:

```
((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?) ([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) )?(\b([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5]\d (?i)(am|pm))
```

I use \b to not to catch hours like `27:45 PM` where without \b it catches `7:45 PM` (misssing 2)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mUd5RD/1)

First version was (not such good):

```
((?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)(\s)([1,2][\d]|[1-9]|30|31)(\s))?(\b[\d]|10|11|12):[0-5][0-9]\s(AM|PM)
```

to not validate such dates:

```
March 31 10:71 PM and April 1 5:23 AM
27:45 PM and 10:80 PM
May 3 4:41 PM PDT and May 41 12:19 AM PDT
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas, what is wrong in this part ? Could you write more details ? My tests are [here](https://regex101.com/r/ERj8R5/1)

Comment: Your regex would capture `,7` as the day of month. Comma is not a valid character for a day-of-month. --- On a side note: 1) There is no need to put `\d` inside a `[]` character class. It is already a character class. --- 2) `30|31` would be better given as `3[01]` and `10|11|12` as `1[012]`, for performance. --- 3) Your range of hour is 0-12, but it should be 1-12. --- 4) What's with the `\b`? It's guaranteed to be preceded by a whitespace, so it's redundant. --- 5) Why are you capturing the whitespaces? --- 6) You removed the case-insensitiveness of the `AM/PM` matching.